Cube.js playground: Cannot GET /
I have built my own custom version of the cube docker image (cubejs/cube) utilizing updated dependencies because of security vulnerabilities. This has required very "hacky" steps like linking local versions of dependencies within the container.
I’ve spun this up in a kubernetes environment (i.e., minikube) but when I try to access the playground (i.e., the equivalent of but not exactly the same as http://localhost:4000/) I get a browser window that only says: Cannot GET /
According to this SO post it’s because my environment variables aren’t set right, but I’ve double checked that NODE_ENV=development and CUBEJS_DEV_MODE=true. What’s my next step for debugging?
